# wpf background worker report progress

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I know how to use backgroundworker and report the progress but with the help of a loop

but how can i do this without a loop

i'm using nreco to create a pdf from htm files

i have this code to convert html file to pdf. so can someone help me to convert my code to report the progress to progressbar?

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
htmlToPdf.Size = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageSize.Letter;

htmlToPdf.Orientation = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageOrientation.Portrait;                    
htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFiles(listSortpage.ToArray<string>(), null, @"a.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually use a loop to report to the progress bar because for every cicle you can increment it. For processes where you dont know how much time will take you want to set the progress bar on indeterminate:

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

Unless your pdf generator can report its progress you will have to do this.